# unable to read stata .dta file in python

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I am trying to read a Stata (`.dta`) file in Python with `pandas.read_stata`, But I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: Version of given Stata file is not 104, 105, 108, 111 (Stata 7SE), 113 (Stata 8/9), 114 (Stata 10/11), 115 (Stata 12), 117 (Stata 13), or 118 (Stata 14)

Please advise.

Comment: Do you mean .dta?

Comment: Yes  .dta files :-) , typed mistake

Comment: If you examine a Stata .dta file in a text editor, the first characters will be something like `<stata_dta><header><release>118</release>` and the release must be one of the values given in the `read_stata` error message.

Answer (score 3):

If the version of your .dta file is 110 or something else that is not supported by pandas, you can easily use [pyreadstat](https://pypi.org/project/pyreadstat/) python library. This module is a wrapper around the excellent Readstat C library.

The great thing about [pyreadstat](https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat) is that the library returns pandas dataframe. Here is the snippet:

```
import pyreadstat    
dataframe, meta = pyreadstat.read_dta('Filepath.dta')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the **read_table()** of Pandas then make sure to include **delim_whitespace=True** and **header=None**.

Comment: I tried, i got error of  CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 5, saw 18
, the data is congested i think, delim_whitespace may not work.

Comment: Can you open the file in the notepad and see how the data there looks like? Is it csv?

Comment: Yeah, i opened it, It is not a comma seperated. It may seperated by some special characters and symbols .